# Best solution on building a Client server app

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, web-applications, wcf-client

I run and play with c # and wonder how I can create a client server solution that can exchange information.

I have created a program that reads and transmits data to a USB device.
 What I want is to create client applications that can talk to this server application and receive information when there is data from USB and can send back data to the USB.
 It is a kind of client-server solution. Where I have support for WPF app, and in the future could create www pages that can display the status icons from the USB device.

The question is in essence how this should be made?
 WCF services / web services / TCP Stack (client server solution)

I need an event trigger when it comes USB data so that clients do not need to ask all the time if there is new data. Is this posible in a web service?

Answer (score 2):

> The question is in essence how this should be made? WCF services / web services / TCP Stack 
>   (client server solution)

Depends. The only sensible answer is "by programming". Web Services are mostly out (WCF does waht they do and more - the old web service implementation is basically an outdated old implementation.

But besides that it totally depends. I have an app here that needs to transport 100.000 data items per econd as fast as possible - no web service could do that. I have some that require web services.

WCF is possibly a good start, but you should learn all the technologies and then coose according to explicit needs.